# Difference between 'setValue' and 'value' in Kotlin 4.1 MutableLiveData?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, code-completion, mutablelivedata

I'm learning android studio 4.1 using Kotlin from a 2020 book.  In one of the examples they are using a MutableLiveData object.  When I try to use code completion with this line:
`result.setValue(value.toFloat()*usd_to_eu_rate)`
the only option is the setter `result.value` tough `result.setValue` does work just fine.  So I was wondering what the difference is between the two and why `value` does not show up in code compleation.

Comment: I tried to follow this link but got a 404

Comment: When I look at the usages of '.value' it comes up as '.getValue'.  Also, I don't see the definition of '.value' in 'LiveData' nor 'MutableLiveData'???  Is Kotlin generating '.value'?

Comment: does this link work? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: @IR42 Yes, it works, thanks!  Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this link - [kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) - provided by @IR42 and other information by other contributors whos comments were unfortunately deleted I found my answer:

MutableLiveData is a Java class and Kotlin will infer a property when the Java class has methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with **get** and single-argument methods with names starting with **set**)

Code completion will **not** suggest the Java getter methods (i.e. **getValue** and **setValue**) but it will suggest the Kotlin inferred property (i.e. **value**)

You can still use the Java getter/setter methods but this is discouraged.